# Java - Wait for Lambda to Finish before continuing

Tags: java, lambda

I have to get data from an API, so naturally I have an endpoint handeler that is accessed through a lambda that, I assume, spawns off several threads to complete each API call that I need. However, After all of the API calls are finished (all of the lambda threads complete) I need to oranize my data. Currently, the Sort method that I have runs on the main thread, and therefore finishes before any of the API calls in the lambda finish.  Here is a sample of what I have

```
for(String data : dataArray) {
    APIEndpoint apiCall = new APIEndpoint("http://sampleAPI.org/route/" + data);
    apiCall.execute(((response, success) -> {
        //Format and gather the info from the response
        apiDataArray.add(DataFromAPIObject);
    }));
}
System.out.print(apiDataArray.size());//Returns 0
sortData();//Currently Doesn't Sort anything because the array is empty
```

Edit: Here is the Endpoint Executer I am working with:
https://github.com/orange-alliance/TOA-DataSync/blob/master/src/org/theorangealliance/datasync/util/FIRSTEndpoint.java

Comment: Why don't you move the `sortData()` call into the lambda/callback ?

Comment: Does the APIEndpoint.execute method return anything, like a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)?  If it doesn’t, you can always use `apiDataArray.add(index, DataFromAPIObject)`, where `index` is determined using [Collections.binarySearch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,T,java.util.Comparator%29).

Comment: You need to create Futures in the call and wait for their completion outside the loop before sorting.

Comment: Use a callback interface or semaphore

Comment: Why dont you use completable futures as you no need to wait for any threads. They just finish things for you after completed. Also, good practice to decouple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using semaphores might be an option. But it will deadlock if for some reason there is no response for at least one of the `data` points. (To fix the deadlock you might need to release the semaphore on errors).

```
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(dataArray.length);
    for (String data : dataArray) { 
        semaphore.acquire();        
        APIEndpoint apiCall = new APIEndpoint("http://sampleAPI.org/route/" + data);
        apiCall.execute(((response, success) -> {
            // Format and gather the info from the response
            apiDataArray.add(DataFromAPIObject);
            semaphore.release();
        }));
    }
    semaphore.acquire(dataArray.length);
    sortData();
```

Comment: This did not work, The semaphore was aquired, but After the semaphore was aquired it did not enter the lambda, and therfore was never released

Comment: You need to register an error handler and release the semaphore on errors.

Comment: Semaphore helped me to write a test case where a function needed to be invoked before assert.